# Is tertiary operator necessary?

Tags: php

Here's the code sample:

```
$boolValue = ($a == $b) ? true : false;
```

When I'm trying the shorter way:

```
$boolValue = ($a == $b);
```

Its return either 1 or NULL.

Is there more elegant way to return bool?

Comment: It's called `ternary` and option #2 does precisely the same as option 1 but with less code. Heck, shorten it even further `$boolValue = $a == $b;`

Comment: Anyone going to ask why he needs 1 or null? Is the default 1 or 0 too hard to work with?

Comment: actually the statement that you have written for ternary operator is something which the operator is rarely used for .. that statement is not used to assign value true or false to a variable but once we know whether the value is true or false then to do something with it..so you may assign the value to $boolValue in either ways but the reason for using ternary operator is not correct in your example

Comment: @DhavalChheda "rarely"? I beg to differ.............

Comment: @LFlare It doesn't, OP is debugging incorrectly. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37074739/2191572)

Comment: @Fil No, it is not. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37074739/2191572)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Oh, my apologies, OP's question was so confusing I misread it as him wanting the output as `1` or `NULL`. Duh.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that `$boolValue = ($a == $b);` is returning 1 or NULL is because you are checking it with an echo like this:

```
$boolValue = ($a == $b);
echo $bool_value; // outputs 1 or nothing at all (NULL)
```

You should check it with `var_dump()`

```
$boolValue = ($a == $b);
var_dump($bool_value); // outputs bool(true) or bool(false)
```

Answer (score 3):

At first, having a code like:

```
($a == $b)
```

Definitely would return a `true` or a `false`. If you are getting `1` or `NULL`, then there's some error or something else with your code. But to circumvent the error, you can use use `!!` to force any value to return to boolean:

```
$boolValue = !!($a == $b);
```

The `!!` converts any value into `true` or `false` depending on the truthiness of the value. This is something like a type conversion for `bool`.

So, as you *claim*, which might not be the case, when `!!` is added in front of `1` or `NULL`, it would return either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @PaulCrovella From the OP `Its return either 1 or NULL.`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar OP has something else going on his/her code which is either editing `$bool_value;` or they are simply echo'ing it instead of using `var_dump()`...

Comment: @PaulCrovella Updated the answer. Kindly have a look?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Definitely... Thanks.

Comment: Double bang is unecessary, and like already said if needed `(bool)` can be used to typecast instead which is much more legible and makes it crystal clear to the reader whats happening in the code.

Comment: @Vincent Agreed. I explained fully as much I could.